# i want to check array's data with mysql_real_escape_string() function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

this function is create sql query with array

```
function YorumEkle($kitapid,$array)
    {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO yorumlar ('" . implode(",",array_keys($array)) . "') VALUES ( '" . implode("','",$array) . "' )";

    }
```

But i want to use mysql_real_escape_string() but how?

Comment: You have a bug. You're inserting one value, not multiple values.

Comment: Print out `$sql` and you will see. (The bug is actually in the list of columns, not the values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array_map function

```
function YorumEkle($kitapid,$array)
{
    $array2 = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string",$array);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO yorumlar ('" . implode("','",array_keys($array2)) . "') VALUES ( '" . implode("','",$array2) . "' )";

}
```

Comment: be like in up.. but INSERT INTO yorumlar ('deneme,aaaabc ' s') VALUES ( 'bilmemne','\'deneme\'' ) do you can see new problem?

Comment: result : INSERT INTO yorumlar ('deneme,aaaabc ' s') VALUES ( 'bilmemne','\'deneme\'' )

Comment: okay got it.. need to escape the keys too .. thanks for you comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Change the `implode("','",$array)` to `implode("','", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array))`. The [`array_map`](http://ca.php.net/array_map) function allows you to apply a callback to each value of an array, in this case `mysql_real_escape_string`.

**Example:**

```
function YorumEkle($kitapid,$array)
    {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO yorumlar (" . implode(",", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_keys($array))) . ") VALUES ( '" . implode("','", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array)) . "' )";

    }
```

Comment: Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in C:\AppServ\www\ebook\classes\yorum.class.php on line 9

Comment: `array_map`, should be applied to the array, not to the joined string, which is returned by `implode()`. Both `array_keys` and `array_values` should be escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string` in this use case.

Comment: @MalcolmX Should be `implode("','", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array));`. Remember the array keys need escaping.

Comment: but i have new problem :) INSERT INTO yorumlar ('deneme,aaaabc ' s') VALUES ( 'bilmemne','\'deneme\'' )

Comment: @MalcolmX: Take a look at my answer for a complete solution.

Comment: @MalcolmX - The name of the fields shouldn't be in quotes... I've updated the answer. Your original function placed them in quotes. The rest of it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO yorumlar (" . implode(",",array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_keys($array))) . ") VALUES ( '" . implode("','",array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array)) . "' )";
```

Comment: @MalcolmX: You are welcome! My answer seems to have solved your problem, what made you decide to accept the other answer instead? :)