# Escaping an array knocks out values

Tags: php, mysqli, escaping

I have this loop that combines two arrays (questions and comments), i now want to escape it so i can use quotes and apostrophes in the comments fields.

```
$result = array();

    foreach ($questions as $key => $value){

        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);

        if (array_key_exists($key, $comments)){

            $comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($comments);

            $result[$key] = "$value~ {$comments[$key]}";

        }else{

            @$result[$key] = "$value~ ";

             }

    }
```

For some reason mysqli_real_escape_string is knocking out the values (leaving only the delimiter (~)).

I have tried array_map / array_walk with array_keys outside the loop but it has the same effect:

```
$comments = array_map("mysqli_real_escape_string", array_keys($comments));
```

[mysql_real_escape_string() for entire $_REQUEST array, or need to loop through it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223028/mysql-real-escape-string-for-entire-request-array-or-need-to-loop-through-i)

[i want to check array's data with mysql_real_escape_string() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636892/i-want-to-check-arrays-data-with-mysql-real-escape-string-function)

How do you escape an entire array with mysqli_real_ecape_string?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` operates on strings - you can't pass it an entire array at once.  You need to loop through the array and escape each element individually.

Comment: thanks for replying, i understand that mate i have tried both approaches (looping and mapping/walking) - i think it goes without saying you need to apply the function to each individual variable.

Comment: OK.  I was just confused because the code you posted didn't actually loop through the array values.  The first block is looks like it's passing an array to mysqli_real_escape_string() and the second is mapping the array keys, not the values.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a simple while loop:

```
    $i = 0;
    while($i < 30){
    $result[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $result[$i]);
    $i++;
    }
```